# paper-input does not line up with paper-dropdown-menu

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have the following markup:

```
<template>
    <div class="layout horizontal">
        <paper-input label="Endpoint URL" id="url" value={{url}} class="flex">
            <iron-icon icon="language" prefix></iron-icon>
        </paper-input>
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Method" alwaysFloatLabel="true" no-animations="true">
            <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
                <paper-item>GET</paper-item>
                <paper-item>POST</paper-item>
            </paper-menu>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
    </div>
</template>
```

However the dropdown is not lined up with the input box. For whatever reason the dropdown gets pushed down a little.

Any suggestions on how to get the input box and dropdown to line up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issues was to use the classes: "layout horizontal center-center".

By adding "center-center" I was able to get the desired result of having the input box of both paper-input and paper-dropdown-menu to line up.

I hope it helps.